# Angular-10 You must pass in a NgModule or NgModuleFactory to be bootstrapped

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

To make my app universal I need to import `@ng-toolkit/universal`.
But, this installation not worked in angular versions from 10.
This is because, a `project.ts` file is missing in `node_modules/schematics/angular`.

To fix this the most recent version (9.1.15) that supports `@ng-toolkit/universal` is imported and Then the `@ng-toolkit/universal package` is installed successfully.

Then I build my project using **`npm run build:prod`** command. It creates the build without rising issue. Next I run the project using **`npm run server`** command. It also run successfully.

When I run the URL in my browser, it shows the error as follows

> Error: You must pass in a NgModule or NgModuleFactory to be bootstrapped
> at View.engine (C:\Users\dell\rithicka_learning\testeee\module\dist\server.js:46927:23)
> at View.render (C:\Users\dell\rithicka_learning\testeee\module\dist\server.js:135990:8)
> at tryRender (C:\Users\dell\rithicka_learning\testeee\module\dist\server.js:132040:10)
> at Function.render (C:\Users\dell\rithicka_learning\testeee\module\dist\server.js:131992:3)
> at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\dell\rithicka_learning\testeee\module\dist\server.js:143601:7)
> at C:\Users\dell\rithicka_learning\testeee\module\dist\server.js:137:9
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\dell\rithicka_learning\testeee\module\dist\server.js:135418:5)
> at next (C:\Users\dell\rithicka_learning\testeee\module\dist\server.js:134339:13)
> at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\dell\rithicka_learning\testeee\module\dist\server.js:134314:3)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\dell\rithicka_learning\testeee\module\dist\server.js:135418:5)

The `package.json` file is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "module",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "compile:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "serve:ssr": "node local.js",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run module:server:production",
    "server": "node local.js",
    "build:prod": "npm run build:ssr"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^9.1.15",
    "@angular/animations": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.2.0",
    "@ng-toolkit/universal": "^7.1.0",
    "@nguniversal/common": "0.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^10.1.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "0.0.0",
    "@schematics/angular": "^9.1.15",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1002.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

install the dependencies with following command as follows:

```
npm i @nguniversal/express-engine@next @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader@next
```

Once after installation, add the following property in tsconfig.server.json > angularCompilerOptions

```
"enableIvy":false
```

and in angular.json file > server > options, add the following snippet:

```
"bundleDependencies":"none"
```

Then you can build the project.
The build will run successfully.